# AWS RDS is slow when connecting from localhost

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

When connecting to my AWS RDS from my AWS machine it works great, but when trying to connect from my local machine - it takes a lot of time.

It is slow when executing some queries(for some it takes longer than others).
Slow means more than 5 seconds for a query that takes less than 1 second on my production server.
My production server & RDS are in N.virginia (USA) while I am in Israel.
When uploading my project to the production server it works fast (less than a second for the query), but when working from my local network it takes more than 5 seconds!

I was looking for an answer all over the web with no success.

Comment: Network latency is heartless :)

Comment: Define "slow" -- seconds, minutes? What do you mean by "when connecting"? Is it only slow when connecting, or is it also slow for queries? How 'far' are you from your AWS region? Are you on a corporate network or a home network? Please edit your question to provide more details.

Comment: I edited my question to add more information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For local development consider setting up a development database on your workstation. You can install the database on your machine for development and configure your project to connect to it instead of production. This is generally a considered a best practice anyway.

Another consideration is to setup a database closer to your region. Check [this](https://aws.amazon.com/about-aws/global-infrastructure/regional-product-services/) page for services in your area.